# I have a timing problem between read and write on a serial channel in gtk

Tags: gtk, serial-communication

This program is intended to communicate over an unreliable serial channel via a PL2303 usb converter with a distant microcontroller. The main loop uses g_io_add_watch to listen for data from the micro.  It then calls g_io_read_chars to read the data and g_io_write_chars to send a one-byte acknowledge.  The micro echos this back.  The read and write are called from within ReadStationMessage.  If the micro is slow to respond, the ReadStationMessage() function is called twice, once to read the data and again to receive the echo.  However, if it responds immediately, ReadStationMessage() is called only once and the echo byte is appended to the data.  I don't understand how this is possible when g_io_write_chars does not send the acknowledge until after g_io_read_chars returns and the micro does nothing until it receives the acknowledge.

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <fcntl.h> 
    #include <termios.h>

    int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
    {
     struct termios tty;
     if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
      g_print("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return -1; }

     cfmakeraw(&tty);
     cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
     cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

     tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

     if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
       g_print("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
       return -1;  }
    return 0;
   }

   static gboolean ReadStationMessage( GIOChannel *channel,         GIOCondition condition, guchar* user_data )
   {
    guchar buf[128];
    gsize bytes_read, bytes_written;
    gint i;
    g_print("\nentering ReadStationMessage\n");
    g_io_channel_read_chars( channel, buf, 128, &bytes_read, NULL );
    for( i=0; i<bytes_read; i++ ) g_print("%u ", buf[i]);

    buf[0] = 0;
    g_io_channel_write_chars( channel, buf, 1, &bytes_written, NULL );
    return TRUE;
 }

 int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
 {
  char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
  gint fd;
  GIOChannel *channel;
  static guchar user_data[128];
  GError *error=NULL;
  guint EventSource_id;

  fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC );
  set_interface_attribs(fd, B9600);
  channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(fd);
  g_io_channel_set_encoding(channel, NULL, &error); // raw data, no encoding
  GIOCondition condition = G_IO_IN | G_IO_PRI | G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP | G_IO_NVAL;
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  EventSource_id = g_io_add_watch( channel, condition, (GIOFunc) ReadStationMessage, user_data );
  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!  I need to g-io-channel-flush after write.